# how to resolve issue to use ngModel

Tags: angular

i am trying to bind ngModel form input text but it's not working here is my
regi.component.html.
in my html part i use input tag with ngModel 
 but this ngModel not print my string value

```
<input id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="hero"  >
```

here is my regi.component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-regi',
  templateUrl: './regi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./regi.component.scss']
})
export class RegiComponent implements OnInit {
hero:String ;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { 
this.hero = 'hello world';
}

}
```

that's it
i want only print my value in html
but when i save my files then 
this error show in terminal
[image]

here is my regi.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegiRoutingModule } from "./regi-routing.module";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [CommonModule,
            FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,
            RegiRoutingModule],
},
)
export class RegiModule { }
```

and when save and look into then vs code terminal

and here is my project stracture
[image]

Comment: What u want exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a form field with an input it is not need to use the NgModel, you can set this way:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
      required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
      formControlName="name" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>

</div>
```

Also, you have to declare this inside a formGroup that bind the form you created before:

```
<form [formGroup]="heroForm">
  // your form info here
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try to import formsModule in your app.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ], 
      declarations: []
      }
    )
```